# Check box and text field validation javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I have a text field and a checkbox on a mobile website that needs to be required before submitting the form. One is a zip code search that needs to be required to go on, and also a check box for a terms and conditions.

Right now i have the textfield validation working...

```
<script>
    function validateForm() {
        var x=document.forms["searchform"]["fromAddress"].value;
        if (x==null || x=="") {
            alert("Oops! You forgot to enter a location.");
            return false;
        }  
    }
</script>
```

but i cant figure out how to add in the checkbox... 
below is the code for the form:

```
<form name="searchform" method="post" action="list.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    <input type="hidden" name="search" value="1" />
    <input class="txtfield" type="search" id="search" name="fromAddress" onfocus="this.value=''" />

    <div class="terms-container">
        <div class="terms-checkbox-container">
            <input class="acceptterms" type="checkbox" name="agree" value="agree_terms">
        </div>
        <div class="terms-text-container">
            I Agree to the Terms and Conditions
        </div>
    </div>
    <input class="btn-submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Go!"/>
</form>
```

any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can check the checkbox's `checked` property:

```
var checked = document.forms["searchform"]["agree"].checked;
if (!checked) {
    alert("Oops! Please check the checkbox!");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the state of the checkbox using `checked` attribute. So, you can do something like this.

```
<script>
    function validateForm() {
        var x=document.forms["searchform"]["fromAddress"].value;
        var y=document.forms["searchform"]["agree"].checked;
        if (x==null || x=="") {
            alert("Oops! You forgot to enter a location.");
            return false;
        }
        if (y === false) {
            alert("Oops! You forgot to agree to the terms and Conditions");
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
var agreeCheckbox = document.forms["searchform"]["agree"];
if(!agreeCheckbox.checked) {
   alert('You need to accept terms to submit');
   return false;
}
return true;
```

Comment: thank you guys very much! obviously i am pretty new to this, and i thought i have tried everything like that.

thanks again.

Comment: you should upvote/accept answers if you find them useful. This encourages others to help people like you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use that

```
function validateForm()
{
    var x=document.forms["searchform"]["fromAddress"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
    {
        alert("Oops! You forgot to enter a location.");
        return false;
    }

    var checkbox = document.forms['searchform']['agree'];
    if (!checkbox.checked) {
        alert('Oops! You must agree with Terms');
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KkYmX/5/

Answer (score 0):

**you can use this answer for form validation in the checkbox**

```js
//checkbox
    var m=document.getElementById("client");
    console.log(m)
    if(!m.checked){
        document.getElementById("bekar").innerHTML="please agree term & condition ";
        document.getElementById("bekar").style="color:red";
        return false;
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("bekar").innerHTML="";
    }
```

```html
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="isclient" required>
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="isclient"> I want you to work on a project with me</label><br><span  id="bekar"></span>
```

Comment: "SyntaxError: return not in function", on run code snippet

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32584219)